# Assign pandas dataframe column value based on first ocurrence

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` :-

[image]

I want to achieve this transformation in `df1`:-

[image]

Wherever chcolate has ocurrence count>1 ,Based on first ocurrence assign the brand the same value

Comment: please review and follow the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples and do not paste pandas as images ever, paste them as construction code

Comment: you don't have `chocoalte` but `chcolate` instead (both with typos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `groupby()`+`transform()`:

```
df['brand'] = df.groupby('chcolate')['brand'].transform('first')
```

OR

If you want orderwise then use `sort_values()` first then `groupby()`+`transform()`:

```
df['brand'] = df.sort_values('brand').groupby('chcolate')['brand'].transform('first')
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this should work where we groupby chcolate and replace the brand with the first element from that group

```
df['brand'] = df.groupby('chcolate')['brand'].transform(lambda r:r.iloc[0])
```